# Cannot get a method instance to function; How to use an Each Do method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, instance

I have an specific method that I would like to call so that I can see the balances for 'accounts'. The method is;

```
 def report_balances(accounts)
   accounts.each do |account|
    puts account.balance
   end
 end
```

I am not sure but I have either built the above method incorrectly or I am calling it incorrectly or maybe I have placed the method correctly in my code.

```
class BankAccount
  attr_reader :balance

  def initialize(balance)
    @balance = balance
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    @balance += amount if amount >= 0
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    @balance -= amount if @balance >= amount
  end
end

class SavingsAccount < BankAccount
  attr_reader :number_of_withdrawals
  APY = 0.0017

  def initialize(balance)
    super(balance) # calls the parent method
    @number_of_withdrawals = 0 # then continues here
  end

  def end_of_month_closeout
    if @balance > 0
      interest_gained = (@balance * APY) / 12
      @balance += interest_gained
    end
    @number_of_withdrawals = 0
  end

 def report_balances(accounts)
  accounts.each do |account|
    puts account.balance
   end
 end

end
```

I would like to see the balances of the objects:

```
my_account = SavingsAccount.new(100)
```

and

```
account = BankAccount.new(2500)
```

by calling

```
'report_balances(accounts)'
```

How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `my_account = SavingsAccount.new(100)` as creating a new account, but what you're asking is I want to see all the balances of a *list* of accounts.  Since each account has a balance, you can do:

```
   [my_account, other_account].each do |account|
     puts account.balance
   end
```

I'd recommend moving your `report_balances` method to a class method or out of that class all together but that's a topic for a different discussion.

Comment: Makes sense, 'each do' has to do with arrays so now I see what Im doing wrong thanks.